# Flutter: FATAL EXCEPTION: main E/AndroidRuntime(18756): Process: com.example.flutter_application_1, PID: 18756

Tags: java, android, flutter

i setup Flutter in my mackbook, created project but when i run it app built successfully but it crashed.

here are logs of `flutter doctor`

```
✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.0, on macOS 13.0 22A380 darwin-arm64 (Rosetta),
    locale en-PK)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.3.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[!] Android Studio (version 2022.2)
    ✗ Unable to find bundled Java version.
[✓] VS Code (version 1.79.2)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability
```

and here are the logs when i run application

```
Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone arm64 in debug mode...
main.dart:1
✓  Built build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk.
E/AndroidRuntime(10518): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(10518): Process: com.example.flutter_application_1, PID: 10518
E/AndroidRuntime(10518): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.flutter_application_1/com.example.flutter_application_1.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.flutter_application_1.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~fomAvxd92tDOKmztvJQklg==/com.example.flutter_application_1-MLY2ZzzozTUFkJvuxMd_xg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~fomAvxd92tDOKmztvJQklg==/com.example.flutter_application_1-MLY2ZzzozTUFkJvuxMd_xg==/lib/arm64, /data/app/~~fomAvxd92tDOKmztvJQklg==/com.example.flutter_application_1-MLY2ZzzozTUFkJvuxMd_xg==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
E/AndroidRuntime(10518):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3365)
E/AndroidRuntime(10518):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
E/AndroidRuntime(10518):    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
E/AndroidRuntime(10518):    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
E/AndroidRuntime(10518):    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
E/AndroidRuntime(10518):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
E/AndroidRuntime(10518):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
E/AndroidRuntime(10518):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
E/AndroidRuntime(10518):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
E/AndroidRuntime(10518):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(10518):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
E/AndroidRuntime(10518):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
E/AndroidRuntime(10518): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.flutter_application_1.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~fomAvxd92tDOKmztvJQklg==/com.example.flutter_application_1-MLY2ZzzozTUFkJvuxMd_xg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~fomAvxd92tDOKmztvJQklg==/com.example.flutter_application_1-MLY2ZzzozTUFkJvuxMd_xg==/lib/arm64, /data/app/~~fomAvxd92tDOKmztvJQklg==/com.example.flutter_application_1-MLY2ZzzozTUFkJvuxMd_xg==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
E/AndroidRuntime(10518):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:207)
E/AndroidRuntime(10518):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
E/AndroidRuntime(10518):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)

 0 
 0
Debug my code
emulator (android-arm64 emulator)
Dart
LF
UTF-8
Spaces: 2
Ln 112, Col 40
Info: Installing build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk...
```

i set the path of java on andriod studion

here are logs of `java --version` command

```
openjdk 11.0.19 2023-04-18 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Zulu11.64+19-CA (build 11.0.19+7-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Zulu11.64+19-CA (build 11.0.19+7-LTS, mixed mode)
```

--------------------------**UPDATE**--------------------------

I resolved `✗ Unable to find bundled Java version`. issue. flutter doctor command is running perfectly, no issues found. but when i run my project, my application crash, and it is continously stuck, here is the output.

```
Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone arm64 in debug mode...
main.dart:1
✓  Built build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk.
```

nothing is happening after this.

--------------------------**UPDATE**--------------------------

So, i found the problem. when i create project by using flutter create command, it is not creating kotlin folder under `android/app/src/main`. when i create the kotlin folder manually and run the project it works perfectly. but my question is now, why it is not creating kotlin folder? i have installed dart and flutter extension in vs code and android studio too.

please help how to fix this

Answer (score 0):

You can rename the folders under kotlin folder and the package in MainActivity.kt is same with path in error message. Because create project by command in Mac will make example folder but config is computer_name folder
renname folder

`kotlin\com\example\project_name\MainActivity.kt -> kotlin\com\computer_name(or something else}\project_name\MainActivity.kt`

and rename package in MainActivity.kt to new one.

`package com.example.project_name -> package com.computer_name.project_name`